# acpi_listen doesn't detect events

Tags: 13.10, acpi

I can run acpi_listen, then press all of the function keys (eg Fn+F5 to dim the screen backlight), but no events are reported in acpi_listen. How can I get acpi_listen to report the acpi events that acpid sees?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 on an asus n550jv laptop.